# set toastr.js options for each toast type individually

Tags: jquery, toastr

Is it possible to set toastr options for each toast type individually?

My toastr code

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "60000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "60000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};

const infoMessage = $(".js-toast-message-info").html();
if (infoMessage && infoMessage.length > 0) {
  toastr.info(infoMessage);
}

const errorMessage = $(".js-toast-message-error").html();
if (errorMessage && errorMessage.length > 0) {
  toastr.error(errorMessage);
}

const warningMessage = $(".js-toast-message-warning").html();
if (warningMessage && warningMessage.length > 0) {
  toastr.warning(warningMessage);
}

const successMessage = $(".js-toast-message-success").html();
if (successMessage && successMessage.length > 0) {
  toastr.success(successMessage);
}
```

I already tried to put the different options types I want in the if statement of the specific toastr type, but with no result.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create class e.g. Notifier which allows you to define different settings for specific message type.

Here is a simple solution:

```
toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": true,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "60000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "60000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
};


class Notifier {
    constructor(opt) {
    this.dflt = {
        info: {
        "closeButton": false
      },
      success: {
        "progressBar": true
      },
      warning: {

      },
      error: {

      }
    }
    this.cfg = _.defaults(opt, this.dflt);
  }

  info(msg, tl, cfgOvr) {
    this.notify('info', msg, tl, cfgOvr);
  }

  success(msg, tl, cfgOvr) {
    this.notify('success', msg, tl, cfgOvr);
  }

  warning(msg, tl, cfgOvr) {
    this.notify('warning', msg, tl, cfgOvr);
  }

  error(msg, tl, cfgOvr) {
    this.notify('error', msg, tl, cfgOvr);
  }

  notify(lvl, msg, tl, cfgOvr) {
    let cfg = this.cfg[lvl];
    if (cfgOvr) {
      cfg = _.defaults(cfgOvr, cfg);
    }
    toastr[lvl](msg, tl, cfg);
  }
}

const notifier = new Notifier();
notifier.info('a', 'b');
```

What is good in the above, you can set your defaults, override them in constructor and additionally override for specific message usage.

[working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/yk48h5cy/1/)

Comment: Seems to work great on your fiddle, awesome. But in my project I get error ` Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`. Which refers to `window.toastr[lvl](msg, tl, cfg);` Is there also a way to not use lodash? (i'll check it out)

Comment: I used lodash to override the default settings - as you can see it is very easy and convenient to do this. Generally you can use any function which verifies if overriden config object has defined property in defaults and if not,   it copies the one from the default object. https://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/yk48h5cy/2/ - working example with jquery extend function instead of lodash defaults.

Comment: You're welcome. What message? please try to reproduce the situation in jsfiddle. It is difficult to say without the code.

Comment: `window.toastr[lvl](msg, tl, cfg); Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined
    at eval (eval at notify (notifications.js:59), <anonymous>:1:15)
    at Notifier.notify (notifications.js:59)
    at Notifier.info (notifications.js:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (`

Comment: this.cfg[lvl] - probably this.cfg is undefined - but as I said - please copy your code to jsfiddle and provide with link - it will be the easiest way to help you. Replace my code with yours and update.

Comment: I figured it out. It was due to the order I included my files. So I can say your solution works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: For anyone not wanting to use lodash, you can do the default assignment in ES6 (Javascript) as well.  For instance, from the constructor: `Object.assign({}, opt, this.dflt);`

Answer (score 5):

You can pass your config options as third argument like this

```
toastr.warning('Please Allow Pop-ups for multiple selection','Popup Blocked',{
    "timeOut": 0,
    "extendedTimeOut": 0,
    "preventDuplicates": true,
    "disableTimeOut" : true,
});
```

This will not overwrite your global config