# ngx-toastr GlobalConfig timeout settings

Tags: angularjs, typescript, toastr, angular-toastr

Not able to achieve using the IndividualConfig and GlobalConfig classes.

```
imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot({timeOut: 10000, positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right', preventDuplicates: true})]
```

Setting the GlobalConfig like the above code snippet will set the timeout for all the types of messages/toastrs, I would like to take control of timeout for each type of message. For example say I want to timeout success message after 2000 milliseconds, error message after 6 seconds, warn and info after 3 seconds. I see this kind of configurations available in Growl messages but not sure about ngx-toastr messages.

I have tried using growl messages in angular 1.x version application

`growlProvider.globalTimeToLive({ success: 2000, error: 5000, warning: 3000, info: 2000 });growlProvider.globalDisableCountDown(true);`

In Angular 6 App
`imports: [ToastrModule.forRoot({timeOut: 10000})]`

I am able to set global timeout which is getting applied for all message notifications but i want to take control of each message type

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878362/6060429 answer will help you. They suggest writing a class to allow 'global' settings for each toast type

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with below configuration
import the ToastrModule and ToastContainerModule in your module

```
  imports: [
    ToastrModule.forRoot({ positionClass: 'inline' }),
    ToastContainerModule,
  ]
  
  or

  imports: [
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    ToastContainerModule,
  ]
```

than call below code to open the toastr with timeout

```
this.toastrService.show(
  'message',
  'title',
  {positionClass:'inline',
timeOut:500000},
);
```

check [StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-toastr-ex) in detail